# JavaScript template literal with back ticks not working

Tags: javascript, dom, string-interpolation, template-literals

I am using a function to create a function during runtime by passing a string for the function name and an object as a parameter. This dynamic function is then set to be called by the onclick event handler of a button:

```
function createDynamicFunction(dynamicFunctionName, dynamicFunctionParameter) {
 document.getElementById("dynamicButton").setAttribute("onclick", `${dynamicFunctionName}(${dynamicParameter})`)})`;
}
```

The DOM .setAttribute function requires a string so the "to string" function is still being called on the object; this results in the datatype name being passed as as string instead of the object itself.

```
dynamicFunction([object Object])
```

How do I do this so I can have the object itself passed?

**Edited for clarity**

Answer (score 1):

This is how you call a function which returns a **string** (if the return value is anything other than `string`, it will be converted to a string):

```
`${dynamicFunction(dynamicParameter)}`
```

---

#### Update:

This will set `onclick` attribute correctly:

```
let dynamicFunction = "foo"
let dynamicParameter = {a: 1, b: 2}

document.getElementById("id").setAttribute(
  "onclick", `${dynamicFunction}(dynamicParameter)`
)

// OR

let dynamicParameterName = "dynamicParameter"

document.getElementById("id").setAttribute(
  "onclick", `${dynamicFunction}(${dynamicParameterName})`
)
```

#### Demo:

```js
let dynamicFunction = "foo"
let dynamicParameter = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2
}
let dynamicParameterName = "dynamicParameter"

function foo(obj) {
  console.log(obj.a, obj.b)
  console.log("correct", `${dynamicFunction}(${dynamicParameterName})`)
}

document.getElementById("id").setAttribute(
  "onclick", `${dynamicFunction}(${dynamicParameterName})`
)
```

```html
<div id="id">Click</div>
```

Comment: although this may a better way to declare the template literal, the .setAttribute function still converts it to a string.

Comment: In your example, dynamic parameter is a string "dynamic parameter" this does work. ultimately though, when the dynamic parameter is an object we still run into the original problem of the .setAttribute function converting it the string "[object Object]".

Comment: Can you create a *demo* like I did? That will help me.

Answer (score 1):

`dynimcParameter` is an object, and when you're trying to convert it to a string, it calls the `toString` method of that object, resulting in `[object Object]`.

I'd advise you to use `addEventListener` instead.

```
document.getElementById("dynamicButton").addEventListener('click', () => dynamicFunction(dynimcParameter))
```

Comment: This sounds like the right answer as it avoids the need to pass things only as a string. However, I have not been able to get the code you suggested or the template literals to work with the `.addEventListener` function yet.